# Java with MongoDb IP connecting issue

Tags: java, mongodb

I write a Java program to connect MongoDb and write some data into it. For example I set up the MongoDb on 192.168.1.95 and run my program on that server. When I use the following code:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
```

It is working and no any problem. However, if I use

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("192.168.1.95", 27017);
```

It always throw a exception for me:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoException: unauthorized
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:100)
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:134)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:142)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:183)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:270)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:75)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:59)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:104)
at com.starscriber.mongoCluster.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

Why cannot I use the exactly Ip instead of "localhost"?? And I am pretty sure that I don't need any username and password to log into the MongoDb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like auth=true in your MongoDB server configuration. If so, you need to log in to your server by connecting over the localhost interface for the first time to create user credentials. For more info see section "Security Considerations" in the [Run-time Database Configuration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/) page of the MongoDB manual

Comment: Ok. I got it. Because I use the keyFile so auth=true.